# Array to string conversion error in php while trying to assign one variable to other as link

Tags: php, arrays

I know, I am repeating the question. But I have checked all others. That did not help me. I am creating recent posts section in which, I am showing 5 recent posts. The problem i am facing is that, Whenever I try to echo the variable $title within an  tag to make it clickable link. It gives error "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\article\index.php on line 41".  Here is my code

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,5";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
            $title = $row['Post_title'];
            $post_id = ['Post_id'];
            echo "<a href='".$post_id."'>$title</a>";
                }
?>
```

The last line is giving error. It is retrieving post id from database and then linking it to `$title` and when user clicks. It goes to that particular id. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code should be like `code $post_id = $row['Post_id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,5";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
            $title = $row['Post_title'];
            $post_id = $row['Post_id'];
            echo "<a href='YOUR LINK?id=".$post_id."'>$title</a>";
                }
?>
```

you forgot to write $row while getting $post_id.

Comment: @Qasim Ali if one of the answers worked for you, you should mark them as an answer so other people would know which answer works for you. :) .